# Java MySQL: Insert special charactar into database

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, insert, special-characters

I want to insert a special character like `✪` into a database.

When I do it like this in the Java code:

```
String message = "✪";
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `messages` (`message`) VALUES (?)");
preparedStatement.setString(1, message);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

It just inserts a `?` instead of `✪`. But when I execute the SQL command on phpMyAdmin it works fine and `✪` is inserted.

The column `message` in the database is of the type `varchar(2048)` and collation `utf8_general_ci`.
And the text file encoding of the java project is UTF-8 as well.

Comment: Did you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3836303/2779842 ?
This should fix the encoding problem

Comment: Thank you! I must have skipt that.
Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I have added the Parameter `?characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the JDBC URL, as @Mathisca pointed out.